# The subscript in regression equations

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, categorical-data, panel-data, notation

What does it really denote, mathematically speaking?

Let's use the common LSDV model as an example:

$y_{it} = \alpha_{i}+ X_{it}\beta+u_{it}$

Y is the dependent variable, x the independent variable. Alpha is the parameter for constant, beta for slope, u for the error term. Okay, so rather obviously the "i" stands for cross-section, "t" for time. But I think it's interesting that the independent variable has a subscript for cross section in it, given that it doesn't really depend on cross section at all. In fact, the way i would interpret the equation prior to having any knowledge is that there is a varying intercept and slope for the equations (Not sure how to write such interaction with the notation, it would be nice to know).

Other than that, in any other statistical analysis I don't believe the double subscripts appear. For example, if I were to create bunch of dummies for the constant to replicate LSDV-style analysis, there wouldn't need to be double subscripts. What makes time in particular so special variable that it needs a subscript?

Comment: LSDV .... = "least squares dummy variable" as in econometrics? So this is panel data?

Comment: I've added a few tags; if you don't think they apply, feel free to remove them

Comment: I believe this presentation explains everything you are asking about:  http://homepage.univie.ac.at/robert.kunst/panpres.pdf

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, but panel dataiin this case really just relies on a bunch of dummies for the varying variables (in LSDV the constant). The subscript most certainly refers to whether the variable changes in the data itself, for given parameter (ie. for the B it changes for every observation, for a it's constant in time), but I don't think that makes much sense. So the question is more about why than what really

Comment: @Dole so far I've just trying to confirm we're talking about the same things

Comment: @Glen_b yes, we are. It is indeed panel data, and LSDV is used in econometrics.

Comment: You could certainly have the effects also vary by cross section, with $\beta_{it}$ or even $\beta_{i}$ or $\beta_{t}$, though that would be a more complex model. I would also distinguish between repeated cross sections and true panel data (with repeated observations for each unit over time). You could also have products nested within broader categories, or twins or siblings, so there is nothing special about time. It's just the most common type.